# pull image from device to pc but unable view in image view in pc

Tags: android, image

I am creating image programmatically and then pull that image from device to pc and open the that image then unable to view that image and getting message that **Can't open this image because this picture is being edited in another program**

here is the code

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.myview);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path+"/test.png");

try {
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
    ostream.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved", 5000).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", 5000).show();
}
```

Am I missing to close the file or anything else after saving the Image into the sdcard?

**Edit:**

I know the answer as given in this post but is any another way without closing the eclipse?

Comment: dont know the PROBLEM or REASON OF THIS Question,but select Image do ctrl+c and ctrl+v open the copy

Comment: the problem is that file which I have pull is in editing mode and can't use for another purpose like open in pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the problem with the older version of eclipse or ADT, after updating the eclipse Indigo to Juno and using with the latest ADT it will work without any error. One of the comment was given by `Drax` with new Version of ADT it solve it. I thing somewhere the was in used and not closed even though your application can free all the object free from the memory.

Just update your eclipse and ADT to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is the exact problem i was facing, solution which i tried

1. Wait for few mins after pulling the image on PC (success)
2. Close the Eclipse after pulling the image on PC (success)

Cheers

Comment: thanx for the reply. I know buddy this solution but I want another solution without closing the eclipse

Comment: OK..Which ADT Plugin you are using?

Comment: m using 12.0.0 version of ADT